# CSS parent height auto, fill child height 100%

Tags: css

Live demo here: **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2u3Ew/2/)**. And my question is: Is there any way in CSS to make `.container` 100% height of its parent `#wrap`, because as you can see `.container` have a border, which I want to make from header down to the footer. I tried everything, but nothing seems to be working. Thanks for any suggestions.

//Edit:
I found a solution. I moved `#footer` into div `#wrap` and removed min-height; Now works: **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2u3Ew/4/)**

Comment: "_I tried everything_" I find that hard to believe.

Answer (score 1):

`.wrap` needs to be height:100%, and it works.

Comment: Nope. When .wrap has height: 100%, content doesn't scroll and is overlapping the footer (which I want to be sticky to the bottom of page).

Comment: @CookieMan Adding to this, the `min-height` set in the fiddle will not work because it is not an inheritable property.  You have to just specify `height:100%`, then it will work. You will have to spend more time working on the hard heights of you elements for this to work with what you have in mind.